# QField hide / unhide features which are not created on the current date

Tags: qfield, feature-filter

During field surveys I use QField to enter sightings of animals. Each sighting is stored with a date. When I visit the same site the next time I would like to be able to turn on / off the display of previous sightings so I only see the sighting of the current date. I tried applying a filter using the current date but did not succeed. How can I realize this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use different style for different dates. Then turn off unwanted layers in map legend.